# node js app deployed on google cloud connection with remote mysql on diffrent server.

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, remote-server

I need to connect to remote mysql on different server and my nodejs code is deployed on google cloud. I have tried with host ip, username password of remote mysql, but giving following error:-

> {"errorno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","fatal":true}

Answer (score 0):

`ETIMEDOUT` is a Node.js networking error. You will need to tinker with you firewall rules to allow the connection.

Probably opening port 3306 will solve the issue. Here's the documentation for setting up a remote access to MySQL [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) and the networking side [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access#advanced_networking_considerations)